# How exactly does ANTLR3 match fragments?

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I'm creating a parser for formulas. I encountered unexpected behavior of IDENT (see code below). Theoretically, it should match 1 or more occurrences of Upper/Lower case letters + digits + `'_'`. But in practice, it matches only single lowercase letters + `'_'` and fails with single uppercase letters and only digits.

```
fragment LOWER: 'a'..'z';
fragment UPPER: 'A'..'Z';   
fragment LETTER: (UPPER | LOWER)+;
fragment DIGIT : '0'..'9';

IDENT : (LETTER | DIGIT | '_')+  ;

table
    :    IDENT '['! '@'? IDENT ']'!
    ;
```

I'm using AntlrWorks Interpreter for testing. Failed tests below manage to build tree up to `tableName + [ + <NoViableAltException>`
Here are some tests:

```
Table[a] - works 
Table[A] - NoViableAltException
Table[1] - NoViableAltException
Table[_] - works

Table[1a] - works
Table[a1] - works

Table[1A] - works 
Table[A1] - NoViableAltException

Table[AA] - NoViableAltException
Table[AAA] - works

Table[11] - NoViableAltException
Table[1111] - NoViableAltException
Table[111222] - NoViableAltException

Table[111222a] - works
Table[111222A] - works
Table[A111222] - NoViableAltException
```

I'm new to ANTLR, but I can't really wrap my head around why, at first sight, similar properties work differently.

Comment: If you are new, study ANTLR 4 please.

Comment: @LexLi, good point, but unfortunately, the codebase is written in ANTLR3 and it's a bit irrational to rewrite. for now :)

Comment: The `LETTER` rule is wrong. You should not be taking the `+`-closure of the character sets. You are taking the `+`-closure in the `IDENT` rule of `LETTER`. Use old software, get old bugs.

Comment: @kaby76, I appreciate your suggestion, getting rid of +-closure in LETTER didn't affect the result at all. Actually I conducted some tests, and when I leave 'LETTER : LOWER' without UPPER, lowercase chars stop working and return mismatch token exception for "Table[a]".

Comment: @Hello_Own_World If you're getting mismatched tokens, what tokens are you actually getting? Does your grammar by any chance contain token definitions that you did not show?

Comment: After downloading all the jars, including dependencies, from https://mvnrepository.com/, and setting up the grammar (with a proper start rule and a WS rule), I was able to get the code to parse fine, using `antlr-3.5.2.jar;antlr-2.7.7.jar;antlr-runtime-3.5.2.jar;stringtemplate-3.2.1.jar;stringtemplate-4.0.2.jar`. You really should be using a properly *generated and compiled parser*, not the "interpreted" parser engine, which is what Antlrworks uses. They are two different engines.

Comment: @sepp2k, terribly sorry for the confusion, I received mismatched tokens due to the test described in the previous comment. Changing LETTER: LOWER affected IDENT which then failed to process "Table". It is not related to the original question.  And no, all tokens that are used here are described in question.  
Frankly speaking, I researched ANTLR3 docs and some git repos and everywhere is used the same syntax as in question. I don't know the reason for such behaviour

Comment: @kaby76, understood, thanks a lot for your time and effort. I will test it properly. If you could provide the code you tested I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Here's my driver with grammar, inputs, makefile. Works with openjdk 11.0.1 2018-10-16, Windows 11. https://github.com/kaby76/so77127333 At the time, I couldn't find the "complete" jar anywhere, so I just downloaded all the .jars. But, maybe you can just try with the complete jar here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.antlr/antlr-complete/3.5.2